# Does changing the SATA setting in BIOS render your Windows installation unbootable?

Tags: hard-drive, bios, raid, sata

I accidentally changed the SATA setting from RAID to ACHI (by reseting to the factory settings) and don't receive any signal to the monitor, as a result can't boot (or potentially see) to BIOS. I'm naturally running a RAID setup and I remember that updating the BIOS has once caused the SATA type (?) to change in the past, but I don't know if the setting was ACHI or something else. But in any case, there was no loss of the monitor signal back then.

Most important to know now is if changing this option breaks the Windows installation or *even wipes the hard drive(s)* — restoring the BIOS settings is at the time a secondary concern...

---

[Asus Z87-PRO motherboard](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/Z87PRO/specifications/)

Comment: a follow-up question: https://superuser.com/questions/1477243/raid-how-to-access-bios-when-a-wrong-sata-setting-is-selected

Answer (score 2):

Yes, switching that will prevent an OS (not only windows) from booting.
Usually, putting it back the way it was will fix it back without affecting the integrity of the data on the drive.

Whatever you do, don't boot externally and mess with the drive until the settings are restored.